# Inserting from a temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables, `sprockets` and `cogs`.

```
create table sprockets(
    id NUMBER
);

INSERT into sprockets VALUES (4);
INSERT into sprockets VALUES (8);
INSERT into sprockets VALUES (15);
INSERT into sprockets VALUES (16);
INSERT into sprockets VALUES (23);
INSERT into sprockets VALUES (42);

create table cogs(
    id NUMBER
);
```

I want to take some ids from `sprockets` and put them into `cogs`.

```
insert into cogs select id from sprockets s where s.id < 40 and MOD(s.id, 3) != 0;
```

This adds sprockets 4, 8, 16, 23 to `cogs` as expected.

```
4 rows inserted
```

As my sprocket making business grows, the business logic for determining which sprockets require cogs will become much more complicated. So I would like to use a sequence of temporary tables that filter out non-candidate sprockets. I believe this is more maintainable than a one line statement with no comments.

```
--sprockets with ids greater than 40 are too big to frob, 
--so it's impossible to weld a cog to them
with frobbableSprockets as(
    select id from sprockets where sprockets.id < 40
),

--non-greppable sprockets have built-in harmonic oscillators, 
--so cogs are not required
greppableFrobbableSprockets as(
    select id from frobbableSprockets f where MOD(f.id,3) != 0
),

--not pictured: more filtering using arcane business logic, 
--including but not limited to:
--whether it is raining on a tuesday,
--and if the moon is in the seventh house.

--sprockets with ids less than 3 are from the legacy system and already have cogs
sprocketsRequiringCogs as(
    select id from greppableFrobbableSprockets f where f.id > 3
)

insert into cogs select id from sprocketsRequiringCogs
```

This code is relatively readable, but unfortunately it does not work!

```
insert into cogs select id from sprocketsRequiringCogs 
Error at Command Line:18 Column:2
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

If I change the last line to `select id from sprocketsRequiringCogs`, there is no error, so I know the problem must be in the insert statement and not in the declaration of the temporary tables.

The one-line insert statement works, and the multi-line insert statement does not work. The only difference I see is that the latter is getting its values from a temporary table.

**Why can't I insert rows from a temporary table?**

Comment: Please do not use `*` in queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess, I have no possibility to try it out right now, but possibly this could work:

```
insert into cogs
with frobbableSprockets as(
    select * from sprockets where sprockets.id < 40
),
...
select * from sprocketsRequiringCogs
```

Comment: Hmm, this works! I wonder why, though? Perhaps `with` blocks must immediately precede a `select` statement? I thought you could put them anywhere...

Comment: @Kevin - based on the `WITH with CONNECT BY` example in this link (http://psoug.org/reference/with.html), it appears that `insert into cogs` must come before your first `WITH` clause.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes i think you're right about that, `WITH` can only be used if followed by `SELECT`, see [http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into cogs (Id) select Id from sprocketsRequiringCogs
```

Comment: Check types... when you create a temp table server assign type itself. SQL statement is correct.

Comment: Do you mean I have to specify the type for each column in the temporary table? How do I do that? I looked at the documentation for [WITH](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html), but I'm not clear on how to give them types.

Comment: Cast it...in mssq cast(id as int) or convert(int, id)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace WITH clause by inline views i.e. use your select statement in from (select).

Comment: If you mean that I can use nested select statements instead of temporary tables, you're right. But I would like to preserve my little temp tables if possible. They cut down on a lot of horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Yes, I do. If the goal is to get rid of horizontal scrolling you're right but if you would like to get sql that works the replacement would be the best solution